# Auto-Generation of Tables

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to Spring Data Cassandra 1.1.2 to work with Cassandra 2.1.2 and Spring 4.0.2. Java is 1.7

Everything works fine - as far as I have tested - except for the tables/columnfamily not being created automatically. I have tried to enable it with:

session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED);

but it doesn't even try to create the tables. At least, with ALL logging enabled, I can't see anything.

I have tried to find some sample code but nothing worked. Any pointers or sample code would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

make your cassandra configuration class extend AbstractCassandraConfiguration 
and override

```
@Override
@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

    CassandraSessionFactoryBean bean = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();

    bean.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    bean.setConverter(cassandraConverter());
    bean.setSchemaAction(getSchemaAction());
    bean.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());

    return bean;
}
@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
}

@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[] {"com.example"}; //com.example package contains the bean with @table annotation
}
```

Comment: done that, but still does not auto-create the used column-families ... !?